# jQuery UI DatePicker to show month day only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

jQuery UI DatePicker to show month day only.Where user can only select month and day (mm/dd). And the date picked as mm/dd format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following only shows the month and day part of the date picker and displays the date in the mm/dd format.

```js
$(() => {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    minDate: new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(), 0, 1),
    maxDate: new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(), 11, 31),
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd'
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-year {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="datepicker" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set properties to datepickr like below.

```
$('#textBoxID').datepicker({ 
     changeMonth: true,
     changeDate: true,
     showButtonPanel: true,
     dateFormat: 'mm/dd' 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to render the calendar to show only Month and Day?  Or you simply want to the get the month and day from the calendar?

You can use the date format option or use set or get the variable.

```
// jQuery Date Picker option:     
$('.selector').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'mm/dd'
});


// Getter
var dateFormat = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat" );

// Setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "mm/dd" );
```

Documentation here. http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

If you want to render only the month and day for the user to select. I would consider using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to create a table or something.